# Matching x words in brackets regex

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to remove brackets from a string if it contains 4 or more words. I have been scratching my head and cannot get anywhere with it.

```
preg_replace('#\([word]{4,}\)#', '', $str); # pseudo code
```

Sample string:

> Robert Alner Fund Standard Open NH Flat Race (Supported by The Andrew Stewart Charitable Foundation)

To match (more than x words in brackets) and remove:

> (Supported by The Andrew Stewart Charitable Foundation)

I have two sources of data, and am using:

```
similar_text($str1, $str2, &$percent)
```

to compare and longish strings in brackets are unique to one source.

Comment: can you provide an example string?

Comment: lol. just though i could match brackets with x amount of spaces in :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're close...

```
preg_replace('#\((\b\w+\b[^\w)]*){4,}\)#', '', $str);
```

Basically, the inner sub-pattern `(\b\w+\b[^\w)]*)` matches a word-boundary (meaning not in-between two word characters) followed by at least one word character (a-z0-9), followed by another word-boundary, and finally followed by 0 or more characters that are not word characters and are not `)`...

Testing with:

```
$tests = array(
    'test1 (this is three)',
    'test2 (this is four words)',
    'test3 (this is four words) and (this is three)',
    'test4 (this is five words inside)',
);

foreach ($tests as $str) {
    echo $str . " - " . preg_replace('#\((\b\w+\b[^\w)]*){4,}\)#', '', $str) . "\n";
}
```

Gives:

```
test1 (this is three) - test1 (this is three)
test2 (this is four words) - test2
test3 (this is four words) and (this is three) - test3  and (this is three)
test4 (this is five words inside) - test4
```

Comment: I think OP is just trying to remove the parentheses around the string, not the whole string.

Comment: @Jake: it's hard to tell, the examples don't really make much sense when compared to the text...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `preg_replace()` for this. Just count the spaces with `substr_count()`, then use `str_replace()`.

Comment: i do not know the words. i need a catch all solution.

Comment: after thinking on it more, that all did the trick, but i needed a preg_match to isolate all instances of bracketed text. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `[…]` has a special meaning. `[…]` are so called [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and match one of the listed characters. So `[word]` matches one of the character of `w`, `o`, `r`, `d`.

Now if you want to match words, you should first define what a word is. If a word is a sequence of characters except whitespace characters (`\S` represents all non-whitespace characters), you could do this:

```
/\S+(\s+\S+){3,}/
```

This matches any sequence of four or more words (sequence of non-whitespace characters) that are separated by whitespace characters (`\s`).

And four or more words in brackets:

```
/\(\S+(\s+\S+){3,})/
```

Note that `\S` does match anything else but whitespace characters, that means even the surrounding brackets. So you might want to change `\S` to `[^\s)]`:

```
/\([^\s)]+(\s+[^\s)]+){3,})/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but this might work.
Here's a pattern string:

```
/\(((\w*?\s){3,}[\w]+?.*?)\)/i
```

And here's a replacement string in PHP to take everything except the leading and trailing escaped parentheses.

```
$1
```

Here's the preg_replace function.

```
preg_replace('/\(((\w*?\s){3,}[\w]+?.*?)\)/i',$1,$string);
```